# Time data doesn't match format specified error

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm a python beginner and am trying to run a time-series analysis with some practice data. I know I have to convert the str date format into datetime. I have already imported pandas and datetime. My dates are originally in the following format:

```
df.loc[0,'date']
'2017-01-27'
```

I have tried the line below in order to get the data into a readable format

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Yet I keep getting the error code:

```
ValueError: time data date doesn't match format specified
```

Is my format code written correctly or am I missing some syntax anywhere?
Any and all help is much appreciated - Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure all entries in `date` look like your first one?

Comment: From that error message, one of your values is `'date'` in the column, which doesn't match your '%Y-%m-%d' format

Comment: try `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors=‘coerce')` any nine date will be NaT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='ignore')
```

Comment: when I use this code, it turns Non-Null values for the column to 0.